# Are certain altitudes reserved for an orbit direction to limit the possibility of collision?

Tags: orbit, debris

Are certain altitudes above Earth reserved (or commonly selected) to limit possibility of collision between objects travelling in prograde, retrograde and polar orbits? Like a one way street, if everything at a certain altitude is travelling in the same direction, the possibility of collisions would be greatly reduced.

Or is space so large and debris so small, that this is not a major concern?

UPDATE:

I had used the word 'elevation' rather than 'altitude' in the original version of the question.

Comment: Space debris collision is a legitimate concern in LEO and GEO, see Kessler syndrome

Comment: @Dragongeek Ah, that helps. I didn't know the technical name for the debris concern.

Comment: That is such a good point I wonder if I should replace elevation in the question...

Comment: Just the Geostationary orbit, and even there its not so much to avoid collision but the very nature of the orbit itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orbits are not reserved. Orbits are on a first-come-first-serve basis. Orbits are managed, though.

---

**Space debris** is a major problem. Sure, space is huge but it is quite populated with debris. Famously, a speck of paint bore a hole in the ISS (not all the way through.) This problem is known as the Kessler Syndrome, and it is a huge problem.

**Space debris is tracked** by NASA and the Department of Defense. Tracking space debris is a huge *must.* Being blind to space debris leaves the ISS susceptible to "pecking."

**Agencies announce launches** to let people know that the rocket that the agency is launching does not have a warhead and let other agencies be aware of the satellite. No agency is going to launch a satellite in the ISS's orbit (disregarding rendezvous.) No-one wants to lose a one-billion satellite nor four astronauts.

**Orbits are not reserved per se**, but they are managed to avoid collisions. Agencies spend a lot of time tracking spacecraft. Without this managing, we would have lost quite a few satellites. Agencies sometimes fail to track all of them, resulting in collisions. One such example is when a French reconnaissance satellite smashed into Ariane rocket debris. You can see more collisions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_collision).

Comment: Kessler syndrome isn't just debris hitting a satellite, it's the cascading effect when one satellite gets hit and the debris produced hits two satellites, etc.

Comment: As I understand it unfortunately there is a range of debris sizes that is big enough to do major damage, but not big enough to effectively track.